# How to add a new row to a HTML table

Tags: r, rvest, xml2

I'm scraping data for historical Dog race results for a Uni project. How can i add a Column to the table with the elements from a different table? Specifically the table before it consisting of columns 3 and 4 
so add the that information to create a 13th and 14th columns on the table below and populate ever row with that information. 
[[image: Row from different table[1]]

Here is the code i Have.

```
library(xml2) 
library(rvest) 
web<- read_html('https://www.thegreyhoundrecorder.com.au/results/bendigo/61001')
tables<- html_nodes(web, 'table') 
tab1<- html_table(tables, fill = TRUE)
```

Comment: `library(xml2)
library(rvest)

web<- read_html('https://www.thegreyhoundrecorder.com.au/results/bendigo/61001')

tables<- html_nodes(web, 'table')
tab1<- html_table(tables, fill = TRUE)`

Comment: Do you want to add column to only last element of `tab1`  i.e `tab1[[36]]` from `tab1[[35]]` ?

Comment: I need it to loop through all the data tables. eg from elements 1 to end. The data is in pairs so tab1[[1]] has the information for tab1[[2]] and so forth till the tables end.@user:3962914

Comment: I don't see that for `tab1[[1]]` to `tab[[12]]`. They all are single row and 2 column dataframes. What do you want to do for them?

Comment: Yes i just noticed that they are 12 tables at the start and im not sure where they come from. Is there a way to avoid/exclude those single row & 2 columns[1,2] you mentioned from the main other tables?@user:3962914

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can remove first the list elements which have 1 row and 2 columns.

We do this using `Filter`.

```
remain_tab <- Filter(function(x) !(nrow(x) == 1 & ncol(x) == 2), tab1)
#Probably it is simpler to just remove 1st 12 elements if you know 
#they are the problem and don't want to include in the final dataset.
#remain_tab <- tab1[-c(1:12)]
```

and then using `Map` we change alternate data.

```
remain_tab[c(FALSE, TRUE)] <- Map(function(x, y) 
                       {y[paste0('X', c(13, 14))] <- x[c(3, 4)];y}, 
                       remain_tab[c(TRUE, FALSE)], remain_tab[c(FALSE, TRUE)])
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. Just a quick question, if i wanted to create a 15th column but add data from another part of the website would i use the paste function as well to the tables?

Comment: ` <h1 class="pageTitle">Warragul Race Results </h1>`

Comment: Yes, you can replace the function in `Map` to `{y[paste0('X', c(13, 14, 15))] <- as.list(c(x[c(3, 4)], new_text));y}`. Replace `new_text` with actual content of the website that you want to replace.

Comment: Thanks that works. Is there a way to get all the tables into csv? im trying to write to csv but not having any luck.@user:3962914